# Y-Chunch Issue 1M - MP-HNT-PM

Tags: digits, pi

I am trying to compute 10 Billion Digits of Pi with a program called Y-Cruncher. When I try to compute Pi it will come up with this Issue and not move for a long while. Any help would be useful.

[image]

Comment: If it's been stuck there for a very long time, shoot me an email with all the details and settings you can provide. I wrote the thing, so I'm interested to see if this is a bug in the program or a problem with your box. But this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Mysticial Would you know of any way to turn off the checkpointing? Or the backups of the checkpoints?

Comment: Checkpointing is always on for swap mode. There's no way to turn it off because there's no benefit to doing so. Also, it doesn't make backups of anything. So that doesn't apply.